# How to removeListener in reactjs es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use es6 in project of react.

```
componentDidMount() {
        userStore.addListener(ViewUpdateTypes.USER_UPDATE,(data)=>this._onChange(data));
        userStore.addListener(ViewUpdateTypes.FD_MENU_UPDATE,(data)=>this._onChange(data));
};
```

Now I want removeListener,What should I do.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `constructor` and `Function.prototype.bind` like this.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount() {
    userStore.addListener(ViewUpdateTypes.USER_UPDATE, this._onChange);
    userStore.addListener(ViewUpdateTypes.FD_MENU_UPDATE, this._onChange);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    userStore.removeListener(ViewUpdateTypes.USER_UPDATE, this._onChange);
    userStore.removeListener(ViewUpdateTypes.FD_MENU_UPDATE, this._onChange);
}
```

Comment: @laszlo if the answer suits you, you should accept it (there is a tick on the left).